# Google OAuth [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

i set up google cloud api for client google signin.

I did api, OAuth 2.0 client ID
also I did Approved JavaScript source(http://localhost, http://localhost:80, my test server page..).

Localhost is fine. perfectly work.

but problem is my test server page.
I registered test server address at Approved JavaScript source( ex. http://stg.blabla~)
but i got error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ().**

**[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.**

**GET** https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=2J9e **403**

The Google login window appears, but there is no action after entering the ID and password.
It just keeps popping up and there is no error.

I already check clientID, app key and so on.. and so weird cuz localhost is work.

What is problem????

I registered test server address at Approved JavaScript source( ex. http://stg.blabla~)

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation, Google One Tap is available for https schemes only if it is not from localhost.

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id